# How to format $output the right way?

Tags: php, wordpress, output, shortcode

I do not know php, I am googling for codes, and I came up on something which I need to do in Wordpress site.
This code shows nothing, but neither brokes site, I think its not correct so can someone help me.
here is the code:

```
$output.=       '<div class="column1">'

      $categories = get_the_category();
      $separator = ' ';
      $output = '';
      if($categories) {
         $output .= '<div class="above-entry-meta"><span class="cat-links">';
         foreach($categories as $category) {
               $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'"  rel="category tag">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
            }
      }
         $output .='</span></div>';

$output.=       '</div> <!-- end column1 -->';
```

I want to output current post categories via shortcode, and this is one part of the same.
I need just help on how it goes from this example, I ll be able to continue codding by following example.

Comment: And where did you put this code ?

Comment: this line `$output = '';` resets to empty the value of `$output`, you should move it to the very beginning on this code so that the opening div is not removed from the output (edit: or remove it completely if the output is meant to have already a value before this shown code)

Comment: function getmycode( $atts, $content = "" ) { CODE return $output;

}
add_shortcode( 'getmycode', 'getmycode' );

Comment: Kaddath, that's it. Thanks. Answer it, I will accept. Thank you very much. Simple things can be hard for noobs like me.

Comment: i think it's no real use that this post have an actual answer, if the problem's solved, that's enough for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$output = '';
$output .=  '<div class="column1">';
$args = array( 'orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC', 'number' => 5 );
$categories = get_the_category($args);
$separator = ' ';
if($categories) {
$output .= '<div class="above-entry-meta"><span class="cat-links">';
 foreach($categories as $category) {
   $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'"  rel="category tag">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
 }
}
$output .='</span></div>';

$output.=       '</div> <!-- end column1 -->';
```